# How to pick only certain elements from an array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array like this:

```
CATEGORIES = [
  [
    "CategA:", [
      "a",
      "b",
      ...
    ]
  ], [
    "CategB:", [
      "..."
    ]
  ], ...
]
```

and I display this array in a form (like this):

```
    = f.input :field_name, label: false, include_blank: false, collection: CATEGORIES, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :last, input_html: { }
```

How do I display only certain categories in this input (eg. `CategA` and `CategB`)? I tried something like this:

```
    = f.input :field_name, label: false, include_blank: false, collection: CATEGORIES.select { |i| i == 'CategA:' || i == 'CategB:' }, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :last, input_html: { }
```

but nothing got displayed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the Array with the String, which will not work. You only want to compare the string with the first element of each nested array:

```
CATEGORIES.select { |i| i.first == 'CategA:' || i.first == 'CategB:' }
```

Comment: Or `CATEGORIES.select { |i| i.first.in? %w[CategA: CategB:] }`